# Copying collection A to collection B with including collections A's sub classes ? For taking online orders. Java

Tags: java, collections, queue

I have several classes . Generic order makes its collection from the things in product class which are just some objects like fruit and computerParts. Computer order extends GenericOrder where it makes its own collection with some objects from Product class and so Computer order has its own collection called computerOrder. Now there is a third collection called orderProcessor for which i think the use of Queues is good with its first in first out ways.

what is the best way to add genericOrder and computerOrder to orderProcessor ? i am getting an error while adding computerOrder to orderProcessor. Is there a better way or i am on the right track ?

```
import java.util.*;
public class GenericOrder <T extends Product> {
List<Product> genericOrder; 


public void compPrice(float comPrice){
    genericOrder.add(new ComputerPart(comPrice));
    Product a = genericOrder.get(0);
}
}

import java.util.*;
public class ComputerOrder extends GenericOrder<Product> {
ArrayList<Product> computerOrder;

public void addDrive (String dType, int dSpeed, float price) {

    computerOrder.add(new Drive(dType ,dSpeed ,price));

}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OrderProcessor extends GenericOrder<Product>{
ArrayList<Product> orderProcessor;
protected int queSize=0;
protected int front=0, rear;

public void accept()// this method accepts a GenericOrder or any of its subclass objects and            stores it in any internal collection of OrderProcessor.
{


        orderProcessor.addAll(genericOrder);
        orderProcessor.addAll(genericOrder.computerOrder);
        orderProcessor.addAll(partyTrayOrder);



}
```

Comment: Just curious, why is the order processor extending from generic order. Why not define an interface called generic order and have each specific order implement it. The order processor then accepts a list of items generic order and processes them.

Comment: `genericOrder` is a `List`, so it doesn't have a `computerOrder` member.  However, after looking into this, I cannot figure out what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @user3586195 If i make the class GenericOrder an interface then i would have to tell computer order to take all of its menthods even cheese and fruit. Which do not belong there.

Comment: @ajb
i tired making it an ArrayList . The orderProcessor still does not take objects stored in computerOrder. 
Im trying to add the collection of generic order and computerOrder which are collections to another collection called orderProcessor

Comment: An `ArrayList` doesn't have a `computerOrder` member either.  None of the classes defined by Java have `computerOrder` members.  `.computerOrder` can only be applied to a `ComputerOrder` object.  But what object?  That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: @ajb
computerOrder collection his made up of objets from the Product class. For example ram extends computerParts . ComputerParts extends Product. And computerOrder had ram stored in it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking something like this:

```
public class Order<T extends Product> {
    List<T> products;

    public void add(T productItem) {
    }
}

public class ComputerOrder extends Order<ComputerPart> {
    //I think, you don't need collection of ComputerParts here, cause you have it in the parent class
    //Maybe you either don't need method like addDrive — you can use add(new Drive()) instead
}

//It's better to prefer composition over inheritance
public class OrderProcessor {
    List<Product> products;

    public void accept(List<? extends Product> products) {
        this.products.addAll(products);
    }
}
```

You can use OrderProcessor in this manner:

```
OrderProcessor orderProcessor = new OrderProcessor();
orderProcessor.accept(new ArrayList<Product>());
orderProcessor.accept(new LinkedList<ComputerPart>());
orderProcessor.accept(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<SomethingExtendingProduct>());
```